# C#: Can't include class from annother namespace

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a strange problem.

I created two classes AdvertisementHelper(namespace AdvertisementHelper) and Doof (namespace blabla), now I want to use the method bad_code from class Doof in class AdvertisementHelper.

AdvertisementHelper.cs:

```
using blabla;
namespace AdvertisementHelper
{
    class AdvertisementHelper
    {
        Doof d = new Doof();
        d.bad_code();
    }
}
```

Doof.cs:

```
namespace blabla
{
    class Doof
    {
        public void bad_code()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is not my first C# program, I have done this many times and I never had such problems.
blabla and AdvertisementHelper are part of the same Visual Studio project.
[image]

> d.bad_code and bad_code is not defined in this context

.NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Make class Doof public

Comment: Both classes are defined in the same assembly, so it should still work with the default of `internal`.

Comment: The code is not in a method ...

Comment: @Fildor good catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have code (a method call, that is) floating around just *anywhere* in a class.

```
class AdvertisementHelper
{
    Doof d = new Doof(); // <= OK, because interpreted as class field
    d.bad_code();        // <= doesn't work!
}
```

You need to put it into a method, for example.

```
class AdvertisementHelper
{
    Doof d = new Doof(); // <= OK, because interpreted as class field

    public void Execute()
    {
        d.bad_code();    // <= Inside a method = OK!
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg i'm sooooo stupid hahahaha :D

Comment: @Simon2215 Whoever tells you he didn't make that exact mistake is lying to you or coding since 5 minutes ago. ;) (We ALL did it - _at least_ once.)

Comment: I've been programming for years and haven't noticed this wtf :D Thank you xdd

Comment: That's one of those things ... you see it or you don't. If you don't , you can look at it for 1000 times and wonder. And then that coworker you dislike walks by your screen and ...